# Label with multiple Targets

Tags: c#, wpf, label, target

To get focus via hotkey on a `TextBox` or `ComboBox` for example you need to set a `Label` with `content="_P"` (if 'P' is the needed hotkey) and bind the element you want to focus on to the labels `target`.

I have a `user control` which is already accessed via a hotkey and contains several `TextBoxes` and and `ComboBoxes`, so I want to cycle through them with the same hotkey. 
Can I assign several targets to one label (How?) or do I need to create a `Label`with the same content for every element?

Answer (score 1):

In your xaml you can give your elements a "TabIndex", this way you can define the path your "tabs" shall take.

As to if you can assign a specific key to use as the "tab" function i would look into keydown or keyup eventhandlers - I think if you assign the handlers to the user control and then do something like this:

```
    private void usercontrol_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.A)
        {
            //Design your tab algorithm
        }
    }
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Just thinking out loud here: using the Tab-function would cycle through all elements of the complete window, right (my described `UserControl` is embedded into a bigger window)? This is the reason I want to use the `AccessText` property, I want to stay within the `UserControl` and cycle only through the elements there.

Comment: @RolandDeschain in your `UserControl` you can use the [KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation.tabnavigation(v=vs.110).aspx) attached property and set it to [Cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigationmode(v=vs.110).aspx).